# Can I maintain textarea scroll position after editing text with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have something like a Text editor similar to the one used here (WMD Markdown Editor). The problem I have is after modifying text with JS, the textarea scrolls back to the top ...

http://jsfiddle.net/qTRhu/1/

http://screenr.com/7uz

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I remember this is an issue with one browser particularly (firefox?). You need to save and restore the scrollbar position and (depending on your design) the selected text.

```
    var scrollTop = txtarea.scrollTop;
```

......

```
    txtarea.scrollTop = scrollTop;
```